# Converting a list of strings to dictionary

Tags: python

```
['key=IAfpK', ' age=58', ' key=WNVdi', ' age=64', ' key=jp9zt', ' age=47', ' key=0Sr4C', ' age=68', ' key=CGEqo', ' age=76', ' key=IxKVQ', ' age=79', ' key=eD221', ' age=29']
```

I got the following list, i need to convert it to a dictionary,like

```
{"IAfpK":58,"WNVdi":,"64":,.....}
```

I have tried ast library and JSON.loads but in vain

Comment: There's no built-in function that does this. You'll have to write a loop.

Comment: You can use `element.split('=')` to split each string into the name and value.

Comment: Should the dictionary values be strings or integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one-liner using a dict comprehension:

```
{x.split("=")[1]: int(y.split("=")[1]) for x,y in zip(arr[::2],arr[1::2])}
```

`zip(arr[::2],arr[1::2])` iterates over pairs of the array, and `str.split` extracts the correct value for the key and value.

Comment: What if there is an equal character somewhere in the key?

Answer (score 0):

If you know that your list is always following this exact format and order, just loop through the list:

```
mydict = {}
for element in mylist:
   if "key=" in element:
      mydict[element.replace("key=", "")] = None
   else:
      mydict[mydict.keys()[-1]] = int(element.replace("age=", ""))
```

Answer (score -1):

Given you a list `arr` of the shape `[' key=aKey', ' age=valueForAKey', ' key=bKey', ...]` (note the space at the start of each list element).

You can use this dictionary comprehension to extract the matching key and values and build the resulting dictionary.

```py
{arr[i][5:]: arr[i+1][5:] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)}
```

Try it out here: https://www.online-python.com/iGI3A2YEnr

If the number of leading spaces is inconsistent (as in the example you gave), you can use the [`lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) method to remove the leading spaces.

```
{arr[i].lstrip()[4:]: arr[i+1].lstrip()[4:] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)}
```